What type do I use in a VS Code launch config in order to run exe files?
I have a project that requires me to convert the Python file to a exe file using pyinstaller -F main.py.
I run the aforementioned command in the terminal and I am able use the exe as intended.
However, when I try to set up a VS Code launch config which automatically runs the command and then runs the exe, I am unable to find a suitable launch type to run the exe file. What type do I use so that the exe file can be run without issues?
launch.json:
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "debugpy", //Cannot use this type as exe files cannot be run by the Python debugger (obviously)
            "request": "launch",
            "args": [],
            
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/dist/main.exe",
            "preLaunchTask": "Package App",
            
          }
        
    ]
}

tasks.json:
{
    "tasks": [
      {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "Package App",
        "command": "pyinstaller -F  main.py", 
        "args": [],
        "options": {
          "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": ["$python"],
        "group": {
          "kind": "build",
          "isDefault": true,
        },
        "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
      }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
  }


I'm afraid there is no direct support to integrate Pyinstaller into VSCode.I'll suggest using the terminal to manually run the executable or submit a issue on github for feature request.
